# PHP: Class not detected?

Tags: php, class

For some reason, when I try running my php script,

Fatal error: Class 'GeoTools\LatLngCollection' not found in ...

However, I have the classes in the same directory. Namely, I am using https://github.com/jkoreska/RouteboxerPHP

and I have all the scripts in the same directory.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Current script:

```
$points = [
    [48.167, 17.104],
    [48.399, 17.586],
    [48.908, 18.049],
    [49.22253, 18.734436],
    [48.728115, 21.255798],
];

$collection = new GeoTools\LatLngCollection($points);
$boxer = new GeoTools\RouteBoxer();

//calculate boxes with 10km distance from the line between points
$boxes = $boxer->box(points, $distance = 10);

//boxes now contain an array of LatLngBounds
//literally have to return string that is printed to STDOUT

print $boxes


?>
```

Comment: thats because you don't have class with name `LatLngCollection` there are class called `LatLngBounds` and `LatLng`

Comment: I actually do. It is in the same directory as all my other files. They all reside within /Users/cygnus/Github/UCSDFoodCrumbs/app/assets/GeoTools

Comment: then `include` or `require` that file in your php file

Comment: So you do have some kind of autoload-mechanism in place?

Comment: I'll consider having an auto-load but for now, I am very confused as to why it says that the class does not exist, even though i used a require

Answer (score 1):

When you write `GeoTools\LatLngCollection` then `GeoTools` is not the directory, but the namespace of the class `LatLngCollection`. However, the linked sourcecode defines no namespace at all, and by the way, no class named `LatLngCollection`. So what you most likely need to do is

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/RouteBoxer.class.php');

$points = ...;
$collection = array();
array_push($collection, new LatLng(48.167, 17.104);
array_push($collection, new LatLng(48.399, 17.586);
/...
$boxer = new RouteBoxer();
//...
```

[require](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) includes a file. So I assume that you saved the classes in file "*RouteBoxer.class.php*" like it is in GitHub.

Comment: Actually, the file is just RouteBoxer.php. So when I add the require("GeoTools\RouteBoxer.php") it gives

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'GeoTools\RouteBoxer.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/cygnus/Github/UCSDFoodCrumbs/app/assets/php/src/GeoTools/getBoxes.php on line 3

Comment: @Faytll So your script is in the same directory? Change it to `require_once __DIR__ . '/RouteBoxer.class.php';`

Comment: Phil is right, I updated the answer. Faytll the problem is that we can't have a look into your folder to see how things are sorted :)